# Wordpress plugins_url function doesn't seem to be working

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin on my site that uses plugins_url to grab the correct path for an attached javascript file.  However, when I load it on my site, it seems to be mixing up the path.

My wordpress installation is at http://serverip/~account/

and the plugin is trying to access the javascript file at http://serverip/~account/~account/yaddayadda (notice the duplication of the ~account dir)

Not really sure where the issue is, and how to resolve it. Any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 0):

You may use **WP_PLUGIN_URL** to get plugin directory URL and **WP_PLUGIN_DIR** for directory path, BTW, what issue are you facing with plugins_url?

Comment: It's returning the directory that WP is installed in twice (/~account/~account/ instead of /~account)